# Return records from multiple separate associations ordered by date

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have users who have certain relevant communications stored as associations.

Notes, Emails & Recordings

I'd like to run a single query which gathers all the relevant notes, emails and recordings ordered by date so that I can display them on a page. 
I'm currently pulling them separately and sorting them ruby side but I'm finding that this isn't very efficient (I'm having to pull all records rather than just the date range for the 20 or so that will_paginate will return).

Is there a way of hacking this in SQL to achieve it? (It's slightly complicated by the fact that Email has a specific date that is not related to the database date.)

i.e. using an array I can get

```
@history = (@user.emails + @user.recordings + @user.notes)
@history = @history.sort_by {|record| (record.class == Email ? record.email_date : record.created_at)}.reverse!
```

but I'd like to try and pull that in an SQL query so that I end up with one response with the relevant items listed one record per row ordered by the relevant data fields, in the appropriate order.

Comment: any thoughts about my answer?

Comment: Added a comment below. Not sure STI will help, but really hoping there's a way to do this as my current 'array' query above is going over 30 seconds and timing out heroku for certain queries.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using [Single Table Inheritance](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#single-table-inheritance) for this. There is two ways to do this in your case. Which one to choose depends on the number of columns each 'communication type' has and how much they differ.

```
# user.rb
class User
  has_many :communications
end
```

You create a communications table with a column `type` (string).

```
# communication.rb
class Communication < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Now you let your communications models inherit from Communication above:

```
# note.rb
class Note < Communication
end

# email.rb
class Email < Communication
end

# recording.rb
class Recording < Communication
end
```

The user model now automatically knows about the different communication types, so you can do things like this:

```
@current_user.notes.where(...)
@current_user.emails.find_by(...)
@current_user.communications.first
```

The simple (but for some people a bit cluttered way) is to put all necessary columns of all three models (notes, emails, communications) inside the communications table.

Another way is to move the details in another table:

```
# note.rb (all you need in the communications table is a `note_detail_id`)
class Note < Communication
  has_one :note_detail
end

# note_detail.rb (this table carries all the note specific columns) 
class NoteDetail < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :note
end
```

And now finally - since you have all records in one table - you can do this:

```
@current_user.communications(order: :created_at)
```

Comment: HI Tim, Thanks for that. I thought about using STI (I'm using it in other parts of the application) but these are not set up that way and I'm not sure it's the best option (the notes table is pretty big) Was wondering if there was a way to get it to pretend the relationship is like this for the purposes of this query, without having to refactor a large part of the application. 
i.e. I'd rather write one albeit complex SQL query, than rewrite the application in 100s of places to deal with STI. 
Ideally I'd also like it to play nicely with ActiveRecord, so will_paginate will still work.

Comment: Hi Carpela, great you know about STI. I still think using the second option and delegation of methods should work. You could think about replicating the same thing using JOINs and maybe a view, but I doubt that it will keep your code as maintainable in the long run as a proper refactor into STI.

Comment: I'm slightly confused by the second suggestion. Am i creating a table purely for the purposes of holding a list of emails, notes and recordings and their routine dates? Do I not need a load of other logic to make sure that table is updated. Or do I need to recruit every reference to a note attribute such that it will now need note.notedetail.attribute ...Etc plus the same for emails and recordings....

Comment: I could call notedetail in your above example note and have the communication table hold a polymorphic association, I guess. Just seems strange to create a entire model for the purpose.